# How to add map value to the object field?

Tags: apex, visualforce, map, code

I am inserting records using excel file on VF page. So based on the values I want to map the product names while inserting.

I am trying the below code it is inserting all (I want to insert record if the ap or wc code matches only) and at the same time when i am mapping product name it is taking null value.

Here is my part of the code :

```
    List<custom_Object__c > CBList =[select Name,Product.Id,Product.Name,WcCode__c,ApCode__c from custom_Object__c Where (ApCode__c IN:PAp) OR (WcCode__c IN:PWc)];
    System.debug('CB List ::' + CBList);

     for(custom_Object__c co : CBList){
     apMap.put(co.ApCode__c,co.Product.Name);

     wcMap.put(co.WcCode__c,co.Product.Name);
         }         
     for (Integer i=1;i<filelines.size();i++){
                    String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};

                     for(custom_Object__c cobRec : CBList){               
                    VFProd__c VF = new VFProd__c();
                    VF.TranNum__c = inputvalues[0];
                    VF.VF_ApCode__c = inputvalues[1] ; 
                    VF.VF_WcCode__c = inputvalues[2]; 
                   if(apMap.ContainsKey(inputvalues[1])){
                    VF.Name = apMap.get(cobRec.Product.Name); 


                        }

                        if(wcMap.ContainsKey(inputvalues[2])){
                    VF.Name = wcMap.get(cobRec.Product.Name);

                        }


                    VFupload.add(VF);
                }
                }

                Insert VFupload;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the map like this

```
  apMap.put(co.ApCode__c,co.Product.Name);
```

Later you are extracting as below:

```
  VF.Name = apMap.get(cobRec.Product.Name);
```

Thats why it is giving null. You should use like this:

```
 VF.Name = apMap.get(inputvalues[1]);
```

Comment: Can you please mark this answer if it solves your purpose